# How to cancel fetch request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, abort

I have a simple form for search user by email in JSON file:

[image]

I want next feature: when user click on button, oldest requests should be cancelled. In this project I set timeout 5 sec on getting data. That mean, if I write first email, than click button and write second email and click less then 5 sec, I should get only data about second user.

To store the found data I have react context. How you can see, I try to use `AbortController`, but it don't work. Firstly I get data about first user and after 1 sec I get data about second user.

```js
const { createContext, useState, useContext} = require("react")

const FindedDataContext = createContext()

export const useFindedData = () => useContext(FindedDataContext)

export const FindedDataProvider = ({children}) =>{
    const [findedData, setFindedData] = useState()

    const abortController = new AbortController()

    const cancelLastFetch = async () => abortController.abort()

    const findData = async ({email, number}) =>{
        const {signal} = abortController
        console.log(signal);
        cancelLastFetch()
        return await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api?' + new URLSearchParams({
           email,
           number 
        }, {signal})
        )
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setFindedData(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            
    }

    return(
        <FindedDataContext.Provider value={{findedData, findData, cancelLastFetch}}>
            {children}
        </FindedDataContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Code on Search button:

```js
const submitForm = async () =>{
        setValidationError({...validationError, email: null})
        await findData(formData)
    }
```

Comment: You create a new `AbortController` on every render. I guess that the controller you call `abort` on is a different one that is assigned to the `fetch`

Comment: @Konrad, but I not rerender page. On submit function I have preventDefault

Comment: Components rerender without reloading the page. Every time props change or every time state changes

Comment: @Konrad, hm, I also try to creact AbortController before FindedDataProvider function, but it not work. Or I don't know how to gettinng out creating AbortController to have global controller